# Automatic retry for the System.Net.Http.HttpClient

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I know Entity Framework has a 'Connection Resiliency and Retry Logic' mechanism to work with unreliable networks.

Is there also such a thing for the System.Net.Http.HttpClient? 
So a sort of an automatic retry mechanism so when the connections gets lost or a timeout occurs, then it will retry for x times.

Is that possible?

Comment: You can do it using Polly, see https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/BuildingBlocks/Resilience/Resilience.Http/ResilientHttpClient.cs

Comment: @Peter; Thanks, will look into that, but I hope it can be something more lightweight or native .Net

Comment: AFAIK there is nothing out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such mechanism. But you can write yourself an event, checking the connectivity all x milliseconds. 
like

```
public class CheckInternet
{
    public CheckInternet()
    {
        Timer t1 = new Timer();
        t1.Interval = 1000;
        t1.Tick += T1_Tick;
        t1.Start();
    }

    private void T1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
        var result = ping.Send("www.google.com");
        if (result.Status != System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success)
        {
            // Your code to reconnect here
        }
    }
    public event EventHandler CheckConnectivity;
    private void OnCheckConnectivity()
    {
        CheckConnectivity?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

Now just implement this to your other class use

```
CheckInternet cki = new CheckInternet();
cki.CheckConnectivity += new cki_CheckConnectivity;
```

Comment: And when you try to extend this with detection of which statuscodes are transient or add a circuit breaker you better use an existing library like Polly.